# Unable to alter table with foreign key

Tags: mysql

My two empty tables:

```
CREATE TABLE person (
    person_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED,
    fname VARCHAR(20),
    lname VARCHAR(20),
    gender ENUM('m', 'f'),
    birth_date DATE,
    street VARCHAR(30),
    city VARCHAR(20),
    state VARCHAR(20),
    country VARCHAR(20),
    postal_code VARCHAR(20),
    CONSTRAINT pk_person PRIMARY KEY (person_id)
);

create TABLE favorite_food (
    person_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED,
    food VARCHAR(20),
    CONSTRAINT pk_favorite_food PRIMARY KEY (person_id, food),
    CONSTRAINT fk_fav_food_person_id FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES person (person_id)
);
```

Needed modification:

`ALTER TABLE person MODIFY person_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT;`

Result:

> ERROR 1833 (HY000): Cannot change column 'person_id': used in a
>   foreign key constraint 'fk_fav_food_person_id' of table
>   'tom.favorite_food'

Why is this and is there a way around this without dropping the tables and redefining them?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because there already is data in person.person_id in any rows (NOT NULL). You can circumvent this by disabling [foreign key checks](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best way to handle this is to drop the foreign key reference from favorite_food, alter the column in person and then recreate the foreign key reference. That will properly recreate the index on which the key depends.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE favorite_food DROP CONSTRAINT fk_person_id;

ALTER TABLE person MODIFY person_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE favorite_food ADD CONSTRAINT fk_person_id 
FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES person (person_id);
```

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/34491453)